# JSON parseError - get json as string

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get json data from a service, but getting parseError when I use $.ajax with datatype 'JSONP':

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSONP'
})
.error(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... })
.done(function(data) { ... });
```

If i try it with other datatype than 'JSONP' it returns 404 error.

How can i get just a string instead of parsing json, i believe there is some linebreaks in json that cause parse errors.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FSEZQ/3/

Comment: @x4rf41 I've tried it... getting 404 error - please check the fiddle

Comment: is the server side in your control here ?

Comment: @Vinod Louis no, server side is not in my controll, just playing around with this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's JSON, not JSONP.

For example, this is JSON:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

This is JSONP:

```
callback({"key": "value"})
```

If the service doesn't provide JSONP, the browser prevents you from getting it (same origin security restrictions).

The way people get around same origin restrictions consist of some server utilization.  You can either right code that does this in PHP, or use a service such as AnyOrigin .

Here's an AnyOrigin example.

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=metservice.com/publicData/tides2MonthAuckland&callback=?', function (data) {
    $('#result1').html(JSON.stringify(data.contents));
}).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#result2").html(textStatus);
});
```

... and an [accompanying fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSEZQ/5/).

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FSEZQ/6/) that shows how this data can be used.

Comment: but that was a server side trick adding a callback(?) which is defined on server side but here @Felix is having no server side control

Comment: No server side control is needed.  It works in the fiddle :-)  AnyOrigin turns any request into a JSONP request.  jQuery turns the `?` into something like `jQuery2910820198209182`.

Comment: you are using a proxy like thing i suppose it looks from your URL. its not a direct request to server the proxy server is responding you the data which is internally calling the url passed as parameter

Comment: thanks, ok. This is working fine. But is there a way to avoid this parse error somehow when I use it as i showed, as it does return data

Comment: Actually its an cross-domain request issue, you need to have server side control if you want to make it work as you called using JSONP. for more information look CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) , else the work around is using proxy server as its implemented here

Comment: but i can see the data from the server, i'm having exactly the same error when i'm getting this data from server side using MVC - parseError, it appears that the json string has linebreaks, when i remove it from response - the json parses fine

Comment: I'm not seeing any JSON error.  I added an example of using the data.

Comment: if you go to my fiddle example, the ajax request does return the data, tho it throws parseError, and you can see the beginning of the json SyntaxError: invalid label [Break On This Error] "data":[{ http://jsfiddle.net/FSEZQ/7/ You could check on the url itself that the data is something like: ""data":[{\n\r"day":"5",..."

Comment: its saying invalid label because JSONP expects a different structure for your data try to run the fiddle in chrome you will get the Error                                                               XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://metservice.com/publicData/tides2MonthAuckland. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (because the request it called from fiddle)

Comment: ok, why this one is working http://jsfiddle.net/FSEZQ/9/? I can feel that i need to study some more... :)

Comment: You can't get the data like that.  The browser won't let you.  It's not a parse error, it's a denied request.  It's trying to parse nothing and failing, hence the parse error.

Comment: @Felix try this URl (http://api.geonames.org/search?name_startsWith=&type=json&country=NZ&username=timetides) on browser and see the firebug Net tab to see the reponse header you will find Access-Control-Allow-Orig... * . this is the reason , this server is allowing cross-domain request

Comment: while if you use your Url i.e (http://metservice.com/publicData/tides2MonthAuckland) in the browser you will not find any Access-Control-Allow-Orig. thus it denies