# Send data to php using JSON (Crossdomain)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

My code is **server1** and PHP code is **server2**. Both servers are separate. What is the problem with this code ?

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("POST", "http://www.3675design.com/Clients/hl/developers/cyber/itgetbetter/email/index.php", true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
        for (var obj in data) {
            document.getElementById("conformation_and_error_header").innerHTML = "Video";
            document.getElementById("conformation_and_error_body").innerHTML = "Share yor video";

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".inline_popup_display_2").colorbox({
                    inline: true,
                    width: "50%"
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
hr.send("name=" + name + "&mail=" + mail + "&youtube=" + youtube + "&comments=" + comments + "");
```

Comment: Any error in console ? What makes you saying there is a problem ?

Comment: if its a CrossDomain request your server side in this case index.php should contain access-control-allow-origin: * set so that it will allow cross domain request for more information see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055077/json-parseerror-get-json-as-string?noredirect=1#comment26417221_18055077 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053280/developing-the-login-page-in-phonegap-using-ajax-and-on-server-mysql?noredirect=1#comment26414746_18053280

Answer (score 0):

in PHP code, u can add a response header that allow cross domain access:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

in JS code, if u want to post a json string instead of k-v, you should change your request header:

```
//hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```